# ">" character when import post from blogger to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, import, blogger

When I import the posts from my blogger account, I get all of posts have ">" character at first.

So example my correct post :

> **Lorem Ipsum Dolor**
>
> This is the post content. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet

But, at import result it gets like this :

> **>Lorem Ipsum Dolor**
>
> >
>
> This is the post content. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet

I've try with all of my blogs in my blogger account.

I use WP 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

This was mentioned on the Wordpress.org forums: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/extra-character-on-blogger-import

With a link to this site: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13458